# Comparing two arrays

Tags: c++, array

I've started reading *C++ Primer* a few weeks ago and there's an exercise that asks you to compare two arrays for equality. The code I made works, but is it good? What should I fix?

If the number of elements don't match, they're not equal.  If the elements are different, they are not equal.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool arrayComparer(int *a, size_t asize, int *b, size_t bsize){
    if(asize != bsize){return false;}
    for(size_t ite = 0; ite < asize; ++ite){
       if(*(a+ite) != *(b+ite)){return false;}
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int ar1[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
        *ptr1 = ar1,
        ar2[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18},
        *ptr2 = ar2;

        size_t intSize = sizeof(int),
               asize = sizeof(ar1) / intSize,
               bsize = sizeof(ar2) / intSize;

    cout << arrayComparer(ptr1,asize,ptr2,bsize) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since the number of elements may be different, I'm using pointers. I did not find a way to get the number of elements from the pointers, so I'm also passing the size to the function.

Comments are appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this for academic reasons, but just in case: there's no need for your loop. You can just do `std::equal(ar1, ar1 + 10, ar2 + ar2 + 19).`

Comment: @Corbin, wouldn't `ar1 == ar2` also work if they were both `std::array`s (and of equal size)?

Comment: @Jamal Yes. `std::array`'s `operator==` does indeed do an element wise comparison. I would prefer `std::equal` though because it would allow him to later change either of the types involved without having to change the comparsion (If he used `std::begin()` instead of `.begin()`).  (Also, `std::array` is C++11 which he might not be used.)

Comment: @Corbin yes, I'm only doing it as an exercise. But thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Try not to use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- You don't need an explicit `return 0` at the end of `main()`.  As reaching the end of `main()` already implies successful termination, the compiler will do the return for you.
- In C++, use `std::size_t` over `size_t`, the former being part of the `std` namespace.
- Consider having your function print `true` or `false` instead of 1 or 0.  You could do this by putting `std::boolalpha` into the output stream before the function call.

  ```
  cout << std::boolalpha << arrayComparer(ptr1,asize,ptr2,bsize) << endl;
  ```
- There is no need for this:

  > ```
  > std::size_t intSize = sizeof(int);
  > ```

  You can just use `sizeof(int)` for both size calculations, so that you can only have size variables that correspond to array sizes.  Extra possible overhead is not a problem because `sizeof()` is actually an operator, not a function.
- If your compiler supports C++11, you can use an [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) instead of C-style arrays.  If not, use an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  They both know their own sizes, and you'll no longer need your own pointers.

  Raw pointer use in C++ should generally be avoided whenever possible, and passing raw pointers can introduce ownership issues.  Passing C-style arrays to functions is also bad because they will decay to pointers.  If you *must* use them anyway, at least for this exercise, then perhaps you can declare `ptr1` and `ptr2` within `arrayComparer()` instead of passing them from `main()`.